# Specflow feature file results into out of memory exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, specflow

We are using specflow quite extensively to perform our Acceptance testing.
Number of scenarios/variants available in all feature files have easily gone beyond 10K. 
We are experiencing a strange issue while compiling these feature files as VS build results into Out of memory exception. If we remove some of the scenarios it builds okay.

Just wanted to know if there is any better way to address this rather than excluding the scenarios

Thanks in advance

Amit

Comment: More details please. Can we have the full error including the compiler args.

Comment: Also does this occur only on vs2010 or also with the 2012/3 compilers?